# YII2. Использование URL в js

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

У меня есть такой js-скрипт:

```
$(".order-event-btn").click(function(e) {
$.ajax({
    url: "URL",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        eventId: $(e.target).attr('data-event-id'),
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //Some code
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //Some code
    },
});
});
```

Скрипт я подключаю через asset bundle "BookAsset".

В этом участке:

```
url: "URL",
```

мне надо передать URL к action "book-event"(забронировать событие) в контроллере Book (бронирование, не книга :) ).

На сервере я могу сделать так:

```
Url::to('/book/book-event')
```

Но как мне получать URL на клиенте?

**Есть такой вариант:**

1. Скрипт подключается через BookAsset.
2. Во view регистрирую

   \frontend\assets\BookAsset::register($this);
3. Во view пишу так и у меня переменная bookEventURL доступна js-файле.

   $this->registerJs('var bookEventURL = ' . Url::to('/book/book-event') . ';');

**НО мне это решение НЕ нравится.** 
Что будет когда я буду использовать этот скрипт не в одном view. Мне постоянно придется объявлять переменную bookEventURL?

**Вопрос**. Можно ли как-то привязать js-переменные к Asset bundle (мой BookAsset). То есть, чтобы когда я регистрирую мой BookAsset, автоматически в исходный код страницы вставлялось что-то типа такого:

```
<script>var bookEventURL = "http://example.com/book-event/";</script>
```

Comment: а почему бы не добавлять файл скрипта только на нужные страницы? `$this->registerJsFile('/js/file.js', ['position'=>yii\web\View::POS_END]);`

Comment: Правилами разрешено такое? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654111/yii2-using-urls-in-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи переменных "из php в js", я написал небольшой компонент, в который я могу просто кинуть данные, а он превратит их json и подключит в конце страницы. Решение я считаю норм, потому что таких данных не много.
Таким образом в инит-методе вашего ассета можно скормить компоненту нужные данные и не делать это в каждом вью.
Поделиться компонентом не могу, потому что он под первый йии. Может чуть позже напишу под второй.

Comment: Спасибо. Возможно это то, что нужно. Я еще подумал над таким вариантом: написать контроллер, который будет принимать ajax запросы и отдавать url'ы. А в js все это дело обернуть. Как вы думаете, норм решение? Вижу только 1 недостаток: по сути на каждый ajax-запрос будет идти 2 запроса: 1. Получение url, 2. Сам полезный запрос.

Comment: Нет. Делать отдельный запрос ради урла это безумие. Я говорил о том-же $this->registerJs только в более удобно обертке.

Comment: Как я понимаю у вас есть компонент, которому вы кормите данные. А как вы подключаете их в конце страницы? Через виджет в layout? Виджет получает json данные из этого компонента и выводит их, Верно?

Comment: Да. Верно!    ..........................

Answer (score 0):

Что если добавить это в layout?

Comment: Нет, переменная нужна мне только на нескольких страницах. Если добавить в layout, она будет на всех страницах.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте элементу с классом order-event-btn писать url в data-аттрибут, а для $.ajax сделайте url:$(this).attr('data-url');
Должно получиться универсальное решение для подобных элементов.